# On Oracle 12c. is there any way to enable the audit trail on SELECT on whole schema of some users?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

Is there any way to enable the audit trail on SELECT on whole schema of some users?

I can only see there is example on auditing on certain table in a schema, but is there any way to audit on whole schema?

Comment: A user and a schema is the same thing in Oracle

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
AUDIT SELECT TABLE, INSERT TABLE, DELETE TABLE, EXECUTE PROCEDURE
ON <Schema_name>
BY ACCESS;
```

Using Oracle fine grain auditing we can achieve auditing of all statements of entire schema:

```
begin
    for c1 in (select * from all_tables where owner = '&schema') loop
        dbms_fga.add_policy (
            object_schema   => c1.owner,
            object_name     => c1.table_name,
            statement_types => 'SELECT,UPDATE,DELETE,INSERT',
            policy_name     => c1.table_name
        );
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I choose only audit the access by, let say, user1 for this case?

Comment: @HaroldChan You can I suppose. But that command is only for specific objects of a schema. I haven't tried that query. But you can and it will be very good if you can share the result. :)